# Sequence with positive limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider $L_0=100$, and $L_{k+1}=L_k^3$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, consider $\rho_0>0$ and $\rho_{k}=\rho_{k+1}(1-L_k^{-\frac{1}{16}})$.

The book I'm reading states that the sequence $(\rho_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a positive limit.
Clearly this sequence is descreasing because $1-L_k^{-\frac{1}{16}}<1$. Besides that, $ \rho_k \in(0, \rho_0)$ and therefore $(\rho_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent. But I can't conclude that the limit is positive. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The sequence is actually *increasing*, not decreasing: the inequality $1-L_k^{-1/16}\lt1$ implies $\rho_k=\rho_{k+1}(1-L_k^{-1/16})\lt\rho_{k+1}$. (The accepted answer is nonetheless still essentially correct, it just needs a minus sign in front of the $\ln(1-L_k^{-1/16})$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
$$\ln(\rho_{k+1})=\ln(\rho_{k})+\ln(1-L_k^{-1/16}).$$
And so, since $L_i=L_0^{3^i}$, we have
$$\ln(\rho_{k+1})=\sum_{i=0}^k \ln (1-L_i^{-1/16}) = -\sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}(L_i^{-1/16})^j=-\sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}(L_0^{-3^i/16})^j.$$
If $\rho_k \rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, we must have
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}(L_0^{-3^i/16})^j=\infty.$$
However, since the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (L_0^{-j/16})^{3^i}$ is bounded by $\sum_{t=1}^\infty (L_0^{-j/16})^{t}$ which is in turn bounded by $cL_0^{-j/16}$, where $c=L_0^{1/16}$, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}(L_0^{-3^i/16})^j=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}\sum_{i=0}^\infty (L_0^{-3^i/16})^j= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}\sum_{i=0}^\infty (L_0^{-j/16})^{3^i} \leq c\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j}L_0^{-j/16}.$$
But since $L_0^{-j/16} <1/j$ for $j$ large enough, the series on the right is convergent, a contradiction.